# Why do "fmt.Print" and "print" behave differently about "Fixing For Loops in Go 1.22"?

Tags: go, pointers, printing

I found "[fmt.Print](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Print)" and "[print](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin@master#print)" behave differently about "[Fixing For Loops in Go 1.22](https://go.dev/blog/loopvar-preview)".

In Go 1.22, loop variables no longer share memory when they are captured by closures or their addresses are taken.
(cf.[src/cmd/compile/internal/loopvar/loopvar.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/loopvar/loopvar.go))

Could you tell me why this difference in behavior occurs?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    for _, v := range []int{1, 2} {
        fmt.Print(&v) // [0x140000a0018, 0x140000a0030]
    }
    for _, v := range []int{1, 2} {
        print(&v) // [0x1400004a718, 0x1400004a718] // expected: different address, actual: same address
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a compiler optimisation in Go1.22 which avoids creating a new temporary if the loop variable is proven not to escape to the heap (not stored or reused outside the call). This is safe since there there is no risk of use after the call completes.

The compiler currently can't prove that the loop variable argument to `fmt.Println` doesn't escape, so the address is different each time.
Arguments to the compiler builtin `print` are known not to escape, so the variable is reused.

The example below show a (*highly not recommended*) hack to force the compiler to assume the arguments passed to `fmt.Println` don't escape. This also results in the temporary variable being reused.

In practice, this optimisation means that many loops under Go1.22 will still avoid re-allocating loop variables and avoid any performance hit.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    _ "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("== fmt.Println ==")
    for _, v := range []int{1, 2} {
        fmt.Println(&v)
    }
    fmt.Println("== fmt.Println (noescape) == ")
    for _, v := range []int{1, 2} {
        printlnNoEscape(&v)
    }
    fmt.Println("== println == ")
    for _, v := range []int{1, 2} {
        println(&v)
    }
}

// EDUCATIONAL USE ONLY
//
//go:noescape
//go:linkname printlnNoEscape fmt.Println
func printlnNoEscape(a ...any) (n int, err error)
```

Output:

```
== fmt.Println ==
0xc000126010
0xc000126018
== fmt.Println (noescape) == 
0xc00011cea8
0xc00011cea8
== println == 
0xc00011cea0
0xc00011cea0
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
I understand non-escaping loop variables don't need new temporaries.

I added a debug log before `return tk` in [maybeReplaceVar](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/loopvar/loopvar.go#L116-L117) creating new temporary variables and the log outputs in both "fmt.Print" and "print" scenarios.

This outcome seems to contradict the fact that 'print' does not generate temporary variables. Could you please clarify this inconsistency for me?

Comment: `print` and `println` have a special implementation inside the compiler (like `append`) -- they are not implemented via same code path as regular function calls so the escape logic doesn't get called. There is no need, since arguments to `print` never escape. `print` is different in other ways too, eg, it can't be pre-empted. `print` and `println` were only added to bootstrap development - using them is discouraged.